# Is there something similar to Vue 2's vueInstance.vm._watchers in Vue3?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vitest

I'm converting a repository from vue2 to vue3 with typescript and composition api.

I have a test utility that helps test watcher functionality:

```
export const getWatcherForExpression = (componentVM: Wrapper<any>['vm'], expression: string): { cb: Function } | null => {
    const watchers = componentVM._scope?.effects || componentVM._watchers
    return watchers?.find((watcher: any) => watcher.expression === expression) || null
}
```

And in a vitest test it is used like so

```
it('should check for duplicate componentInput names, when name input changes', async () => {
        // Get the watcher for the name input
        const onNameChanged = getWatcherForExpression(component.vm, 'componentInput.name');
        jest.spyOn(onNameChanged, 'cb');

        // Set the name input value
        const nameInput = component.find('.component-class input');
        await nameInput.setValue('test2');

        // Expect the watcher to have been called and the name to have been set
        expect(component.vm.componentInput.name).toEqual('test2');
        expect(onNameChanged.cb).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
})
```

I need it to test that a component's internal method has been called when props have been updated.

**Is there an equivalent to `wrapper.vm._watchers` in Vue3?** Because I don't see anything useful, even after looking at [Vue Test Utils documentation](https://test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#vm) and [Vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/component-instance.html)